# non-conformable arguments when read %*%

Tags: r, statistics, spatial, gwr

This is my Code, maybe you know the method of **Geographically Weighted Negative Binomial** and can fix the error

```
> gemes2=function(X,y,W1,phi1,b1){
+   beta=matrix(c(0),6,6,byrow=T)
+   #beta[1,1]=phi1
+   #beta[1,2:6]=b1
+   satu=rep(1,38)
+   dua=as.matrix(satu)
+   bxx=rbind(c(phi1,beta[1,2:6]))
+   for(i in 1:6){
+     Xb1=as.matrix(X)%*%as.matrix(bxx)
+     mu1=exp(Xb1+log(n))
+     delta11=((log(1+phi1*mu1)-digamma(y+(1/phi1))+digamma(1/phi1))/phi1^2)+
+       ((y-mu1)/((1+phi1*mu1)*phi1))
+     delta11=as.matrix(delta11)
+     p11= t(satu) %*% W1 %*% delta11
+     delta21=(y-mu1)/(1+phi1*mu1)
+     delta21=as.matrix(delta21)
+     p21=t(X)%*%as.matrix(W1)%*%delta21
+     p21=as.matrix(p21)
+     gt1=rbind(p11,p21)
+     delta31=((trigamma(y+(1/phi1))-trigamma(1/phi1))/phi1^4)+((2*digamma(y+(1/phi1))-
+                                                                  2*digamma(1/phi1)-2*log(1+phi1*mu1))/phi1^3)+((2*mu1)/(phi1^2*(1+phi1*mu1)))+
+       (((y+(1/phi1))*mu1^2)/(1+phi1*mu1)^2)-(y/phi1^2)
+     delta31=as.matrix(delta31)
+     p31=t(satu)%*%W1%*%delta31
+     p31=as.matrix(p31)
+     delta41=mu1*(mu1-y)/(1+phi1*mu1)^2
+     delta41=as.matrix(delta41)
+     p41=t(X)%*%W1%*%delta41
+     p41=as.matrix(p41)
+     h11=rbind(p31,p41)
+     delta51=mu1*(phi1*y+1)/(1+phi1*mu1)^2
+     delta51=t(delta51)
+     delta51=c(delta51)
+     delta51=as.matrix(diag(delta51))
+     p51=t(x)%*%as.matrix(W1)%*%delta51%*%as.matrix(x)
+     p51=-1*p51
+     p51=as.matrix(p51)
+     h21=rbind(t(p41),p51)
+     H1=cbind(h11,h21)
+     H11=ginv(H1)
+     beta[i,]=(t(b01)-H11%*%gt1)
+     phi1=beta[i,1]
+     b01=t(beta[i,])
+     bxx=beta[i,2:6]}
+   return(list(beta=beta,hessian=H1))}
> 
> #Fungsi GWNBR
> gwnbr1=function(x,y,W,teta){
+   beta=bn$coefficients
+   param=matrix(c(0),nrow(x),ncol(x)+1,byrow=T)
+   zhit=matrix(c(0),nrow(x),ncol(x),byrow=T)
+   for(i in 1:38){
+     ww=as.matrix(diag(W[i,]))
+     hit=gemes2(x,y,ww,teta,beta)
+     parameter=hit$beta
+     param[i,]=hit$beta[6,]
+     write.csv(hit$hessian,file=paste("hessian",i,".csv"))
+     invh= -ginv(as.matrix(hit$hessian))
+     for(j in 1:ncol(x)){
+       zhit[i,j]=param[i,j]/invh[j+1,j+1]}}
+   return(list(koefisien=param,Z_hitung=zhit))}
> 
> 
> #Memanggil GWNBR
> datad=read.table("D:/data baru lg.csv",header=T, sep=";")
> bobot=as.matrix(read.table("D:/pembobot fix.csv",header=F,sep=";"))
> xx=datad[,3:6]
> bny=datad[,2]
> x=as.matrix(cbind(1,xx))
> y=c(bny)
> mod=gwnbr1(x,y,bobot,9.21)
Error in as.matrix(X) %*% as.matrix(bxx) : non-conformable arguments
```

Today i can fix the error, but when i was change the predictor variables in data. i don't know why the syntax error again. my laptop can't read `%*%` in r

As you can see I get the error, from the causality method:`Error in as.matrix(X) %*% as.matrix(bxx) : non-conformable arguments`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make your code minimally reproducible. This means focusing only on the aspect of the code that is providing the error, and providing an example of your data such that the error can be reproduced.

Comment: There is a long bar at the bottom of your keyboard, called the "space bar", please use it to make your code human-readable.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).